# CallKit reinitializing causes com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4 (UnknownCallUUID)

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

My iOS VoIP app uses CallKit in order to support native call integration feature. At first launch everything is working fine, but if I reinitialize CXProvider and CXCallController (in order to disable/enable feature), after incoming call hangup I receive error "com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4".

```
@implementation CallKitHandler
- (void) configureCallKitWith
{
    ...
    self.callKitProvider = [[CXProvider alloc]  initWithConfiguration:_cxpConfiguration];
    [_callKitProvider setDelegate:self queue:nil];

    self.callKitCallController = [CXCallController new];
    [_callKitCallController.callObserver setDelegate:self      queue:nil];
    ...
}
```

```
- (void) requestEndCallActionWithCall:(Call*) callEnded
{
    CXEndCallAction* endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.callUUId];
    CXTransaction* transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];
    OTCLogVerbose (@"requestEndCallActionWithCall '%@' : %@", callEnded.reference, transaction);

    [self.callKitCallController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError* error) {
        if (error)
        {
            OTCLogWarn (@"requestEndCallActionWithCall failed for '%@': %@", _callUUId, [self errorDescriptionOf: error]);
```

I tried to make my CallKitHandler class as singleton, and it seems to be working, is it the only possible solution? Should you avoid reinitializing CallKit during app's runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider) says:

> A VoIP app should create only one instance of `CXProvider` and store it for use globally.

So, yes: you should avoid instantiating the `CXProvider` every time you want to reconfigure it. Just keep a global reference and reconfigure it if you need to.